# How can I make some methods from an array defined outside the class def

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
This works:

class MyAwesomeClass

variable_of_doom = ["things", "stuff", "chunky_bacon"]  

  variable_of_doom.each do |name|
    define_method("#{name}") do
      puts name
    end
  end
end

puts (MyAwesomeClass.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods).inspect

# => ["things", "stuff", "chunky_bacon"]
```

This does not, but this is what I need:

```
variable_of_doom = ["things", "stuff", "chunky_bacon"]  

class MyAwesomeClass

  variable_of_doom.each do |name|
    define_method("#{name}") do
      puts name
    end
  end
end

puts (MyAwesomeClass.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods).inspect
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method ‘variable_of_doom’ for MyAwesomeClass:Class

# => method <class:MyAwesomeClass>  in untitled 4 at line 9
# => method <main>  in untitled 4 at line 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, a `class` (or `def`) block demarcates a new, separate scope in which local variables from surrounding scopes are not accessible. If you need surrounding local variables to be in scope, you can get around this using blocks, like:

```
 variable_of_doom = ["things", "stuff", "chunky_bacon"]

 MyAwesomeClass.class_eval do
   variable_of_doom.each do |var|
     # do whatever you need here
   end
 end
```

In Pragmatic Bookshelf's *Ruby Metaprogramming*, they describe the use of this technique as "scope gates": use `class` or `def` blocks when you want to create a new scope for local variables, use blocks when you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Your question boils down to this failing example:

```
variable_of_doom = %w(famine plague flood war pestilence drought television)

class MyAwesomeClass
  # undefined local variable or method `variable_of_doom' for MyAwesomeClass:Class
  puts variable_of_doom
end
```

Are the variables of doom constant? If so, the following works, because classes have access to constants declared outside their own class definition:

```
VARIABLE_OF_DOOM = %w(famine plague flood war pestilence drought dos)

class MyAwesomeClass
  puts VARIABLE_OF_DOOM
end
```

If you need the doom-worthy variables to be dynamic, you could create a module or class with a method that knows how to deliver them.

```
module VarsOfDoom
  VOD = %w(famine plague flood war pestilence drought computer-mouse)

  def self.dynamic
    VOD.shuffle
  end
end

class MyAwesomeClass
  # Works because the module VarsOfDoom is itself a constant.
  puts VarsOfDoom::VOD
  puts
  puts VarsOfDoom.dynamic
end
```

I would not resort to making `$variables_of_doom` a global. It's not necessary and should be avoided on principle.

Comment: +1 for the thoroughness and the humor. I could not get it to work for me, but I suspect noobness to be the culprit there. Alex D's answer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, global variables need are indicated by `$` just like instance variables are indicated with `@`.  So this works:

```
$variable_of_doom = ["things", "stuff", "chunky_bacon"] 
class MyAwesomeClass

  $variable_of_doom.each do |name|
    define_method("#{name}") do
      puts name
    end
  end
end

puts (MyAwesomeClass.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods).inspect
# => [:things, :stuff, :chunky_bacon]
```

Comment: I don't know much, but I do know people are really down on global variables. It would probably work fine in my case, as this code is not likely to cause conflicts with other people's stuff. That having been said, that little line at the end is solid gold. "puts (MyAwesomeClass.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods).inspect"

Comment: @John, Global variables like this do suck, but you seemed to want to use one and didn't understand why it didn't work, so I explained how to make it work. I don't know why you didn't like having `variable_of_doom` inside `MyAwesomeClass` so I didn't propose a better alternative, though I suspect making it a constant inside the class would have been best.

Answer (score 0):

How to resolve the issue has been told in other answer. I would like to suggest you to do such `instropection` as below to check the scope rule :

```
variable_of_doom = ["things", "stuff", "chunky_bacon"] 

defined? variable_of_doom # => "local-variable"
local_variables.include? :variable_of_doom # => true

class MyAwesomeClass
  p defined?(variable_of_doom)
  p local_variables.include?(:variable_of_doom )
end
# >> nil
# >> false
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to make glabal variables, instead, moving variable_of_doom into Class scopes would be a god idea.